# Why does Ruby require all similar properties to do a sort?

Tags: ruby

As long as all are a string or all are a symbol, sort returns what I expect. But some calls fail because there are objects of mixed property types (some symbols, some strings).

```
{"action" => "ok", "test" => "a"}.sort
# => [["action", "ok"], ["test", "a"]]

{:action => "ok", :test => "a"}.sort
# => [[:action, "ok"], [:test, "a"]]

{"action" => "ok", :test => "a"}.sort
# => ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed
```

Why is this? Shouldn't Ruby be calling `to_s` on each member?

Comment: "Shouldn't Ruby be calling to_s on each member?" - of course not. That'd be super-silly.

Comment: How else is it going to compare symbols to strings?

Comment: Well, it's not [going to]. `[:foo, 'bar'].sort
ArgumentError: comparison of Symbol with String failed`

Comment: You can't sort incomparable things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort` calls `to_a` on the hash, which makes the hash into an array of arrays (key-value pairs). Then `sort` compares the elements, which would be a comparison of an array with an array.

Within the `Array` class, comparison is defined as comparison of its elements from the beginning with the corresponding element in the other array.

When each element within the arrays are compared, a way to compare has to be defined between the elements. `String` class has its comparison defined against another `String`, but not against a `Symbol`. `Symbol` class has its comparison defined against another `Symbol`, but not against another `String`. In your offending case, you need to compare the string `"action"` against the symbol `:test`, which is not defined. In order to make it work, you need to override the definition of comparison for `String` (and for `Symbol` for generality) to define comparison of `String` against a `Symbol` (as well as against a `String`). One way to do it is as follows:

```
module PreString
  def <=> other; super(other.to_s) end
end

class String; prepend PreString end

module PreSymbol
  def <=> other; super(other.to_sym) end
end

class Symbol; prepend PreSymbol end

{"action" => "ok", :test => "a"}.sort
# => [["action", "ok"], [:test, "a"]]
```

**Edit** If you are concerned about creating random symbols (as with @SergioTulentsev), you can do the following and forget about `PreSymbol` defined above:

```
module Symbol
  def <=> other; to_s <=> other end
end
```

---

Shouldn't Ruby be calling `to_s` on each member?---No.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) says it returns and array, so I believe it creates a temporary array.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating symbols left and right. They're still not GC-able, are they?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev In the newest version, they are, I think. But that is a good point.

Comment: I don't think we should be recommending dangerous monkey patches like this before we know what the user is really trying to do, which is probably something simple like sorting a hash by its keys, which can be done easily with `.sort_by { |a| a[0].to_s }`.

Comment: Yes, but `Enumerable#sort` doesn't know the receiver is a hash, so it's not converting the hash to an array. Rather, `Hash#each` is converting each key-value pair of the hash to a 2-element array that it passes to `sort`. Evidently, `sort` accumulates these pairs in an array before beginning that sort operation. You know all this, but I think your first sentence is misleading.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think you are right, my answer is not accurate, probably. But I don't how to correct it. Perhaps you can do it for me.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I see your point. But probably the OP should have rather used `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

Comment: Sorry, but I suffer from [Redactophobia](http://www.islandnet.com/~egbird/dict/r.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer(s)!

Comment: Here's an interesting piece of trivia. I glanced at the source for `Enumerable#sort` and noticed that it dups the array it has built and then invokes `sort!`. If the receiver was a hash (or an instance of any class that `include`s `Enumerable` and does not implement `sort`) I would think the `dup` operation is unnecessary. Note `Array` implements `sort`. I've probably overlooked something.

Answer (score -2):

Ruby's sort is done using `<=>` operator. The `<=>` operator only works on the same types of things. So you can compare two strings or two symbols or two numbers, etc. But you can't compare two different things.

Ruby should not `to_s` each thing to do a comparison.

If you need to compare in this way, you can give a block to sort where you do the conversion yourself.

```
{"action" => "ok", :test => "a"}.sort_by {|a| a[0].to_s}
```

Note: As suggested by David Grayson in the comments, you likely want to sort the hash by keys, so this reaches into the argument passed to sort and pulls out the first element which is the key.

Comment: Or, equivalently, you can do `.sort_by { |a| a.to_s }`.  But this seems odd to me because `a` will be an array that contains a key and a value.  If you want to just sort by the keys, do `.sort_by { |a| a[0].to_s }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is actually a major point. That is the reason this answer is wrong. (Hint: methods can be redefined.)

Comment: It's a good point about the hash. I was mainly explaining why what he was doing wouldn't work with minimal changes, but it would be better to give a solution that actually does what the OP likely wanted, which was to sort the hash.

Comment: You can't use `sort {|a| a[0].to_s}`. It results in `ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed`. Perhaps you mean `sort_by {|a| a[0].to_s}`, but sorting a hash is really not very useful and is the more important question to be dealt with.

Comment: Yes, I had a typo changing to the suggested hash friendly one and left off the `_by`. That's fixed. I still think this is a better answer than the ridiculous answer to monkey patch String and Symbol. Whether sorting a hash is right or not is not really the question. It's what the OP wants to do. The OP just didn't understand the correct comparison.